# Fedora - SELinux - livecd-tools

Tags: fedora, selinux

I'm using `livecd-tools` to build an image and I am able to consistently build images now, but upon bootup and login, I get "no shell - permission denied".  After reading about that error, I saw it is related to SELinux.

I'm guessing this may be because part of my installation involves copying files to the installation.  I tried running `fixfiles`, but that errored out, is there something else I should run to fix this SELinux issue?

Comment: What error did fixfiles throw?

Comment: I put a new filesystem on the drive and I don't have any problems now.  I can also bootup to the images so they work.  I never saw any errors in dmesg so I'm not sure what the problem was?